# Passing PHP-variable to Javascript doesn't work via PHP-function (not about global variables)

Tags: javascript, php, function

I want to pass "$var_external" to the Javascript "SHOW".

HERE I call the function:

```
<?php
include("test23.php");

$call_function = test23(); 
?>
```

---

THIS is the function test23.php:

```
<?php

function test23() {

$var_external = 9999;       // This doesn't work

print("<a href=\"dummy\" id=\"SHOW\">Activate script</a>");

}
?>    

<script type="text/javascript">

$( function () {
  $("a#SHOW").toggle( function() {  

    var var_external =  <?php echo $var_external; ?>;

    alert(var_external);

  }, 
  function () {
    return false;
  });
});
```

If you click on "Activate script" the $var_external should be passed to Javascript.

When $var_external is set **inside** the PHP-function it doesn't work.

When I put $var_external **outside** the PHP-function it works.

Why doen't it work inside the PHP-function?

Comment: When echo'ing variables to JavaScript in PHP, always use `json_encode` to properly encode the variable, otherwise you're not safe.

Comment: I don't need a global variable. That was just a try to get it work, but it didn't. I skipped the global statement now, because that was not the point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use global variables, it's a poor practice to get in the habit of.

You should pass the value into the function as an argument:

```
function test23( $var_external ){
  // do stuff to modify it
  return $var_external;
}
```

Then print the result:

```
<?php print test23($var_external); ?>
```

It's hard to give better advice because I don't know what the values are really for, and why they're being modified.

A few other tips:

- The variable has to created outside the function before `global` would work.
- Be sure a value is always printed, if it prints an empty/null val, the javascript will break. Or, use quotes and then convert to a number or whatever you need

Comment: I don't need to global $var_external. That was just a guess to get it work, but it didn't

Comment: It doesn't matter if you need it global or not. The PHP echo statement you use, assumed it's outside a function. Either ditch the function in the script, or change the echo statement to call the function instead. My example shows that recommendation

Comment: I removed the Java Script code from the PHP-function and put it in the call to the PHP-function. Now it's clearer that the variable must be returned from the PHP-function.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem, use ''

```
var var_external =  '<?php echo $var_external; ?>';
```

Seems java script crash if php echo text and not crash if php echo int.